# Sitecore containers exit with "Failed to update IIS configuration" error

Tags: docker

I am attempting to run Sitecore 10.0 in containers, but the environment fails to start successfully. If I try to access my Content Management container, I get a 404 error:

```
404 page not found
```

I see that my `cm` and `xconnect` containers have exited. Running `docker-compose logs cm` or `docker-compose logs xconnect` reveals the following error:

```
Service 'w3svc' has been stopped
APPCMD failed with error code 259
Failed to update IIS configuration
```

How can I get my container environment to start successfully?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This error is due to an [issue with Service Monitor](https://github.com/microsoft/IIS.ServiceMonitor/issues/34) which affects Sitecore containers based on Windows Server Core LTSC2019. The original entrypoint for the Sitecore CM container in 10.0 used `ServiceMonitor.exe` to start and monitor the `w3wp` service.

As this issue only affects LTSC2019, one fix is to switch to one of the [SAC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started-19/servicing-channels-19#semi-annual-channel) images available from Sitecore by changing the `SITECORE_VERSION` environment variable that's used in the default Compose configuration.

```
SITECORE_VERSION=10.0.0-1909
```

Sitecore has also resolved this issue in the latest patch releases for Sitecore 10.0.1 by replacing `ServiceMonitor.exe` with a custom script, one that was already being used in Sitecore 10.1. To get this update, ensure your `SITECORE_VERSION` is either `10.0-ltsc2019` or `10.0.1-ltsc2019` and pull the latest images:

```
docker-compose -f .\docker-compose.yml pull
```

If you are using Sitecore Docker Tools and its [development entrypoint](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/100/developer-tools/en/deploying-files-into-running-containers.html#the-sitecore-docker-tools-assets-image-development-entrypoint), you need to ensure you have the latest patch release of it as well.

```
docker pull scr.sitecore.com/tools/sitecore-docker-tools-assets:10.0.0-1809
```

If you are [building custom images](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/100/developer-tools/en/building-custom-sitecore-images.html) for your Sitecore containers, after pulling the latest base images and Sitecore Docker Tools images, you'll also need to rebuild your containers.

```
docker-compose build
```

Answer (score 3):

If, for any reason, rebuilding your custom images is not an option or you are using custom images provided by a third party, this workaround will be helpful to get all the containers started correctly.

Re-run the command to start the containers a couple times in a row:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Usually 2-3 times is enough for all the IIS/ServiceMonitor based containers to start without error and stay started.